# delete all files in folder which are not imported by files in another folder using vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

example:

```
folderA/
 - file1 imports ../folderB/file3
 - file2 imports ../folderB/file4

folderB/
 - file3
 - file4
 - file5
```

In this case I would want to delete folderB/file5. Is there a vs code extension that does this?

Comment: To understand what you are asking, when you are saying `file1 imports ../folderB/file3` how does file1 import that? Are you referring to a specific language that imports other files? Does vscode have some sort of function that I'm unaware of?

Comment: I am thinking of JavaScript import statements here. I am not sure about relevant vscode functions for this topic